# How can I extract an input value by id with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a casperjs problem. I can't extract value from an id with javascript.

I am opening google, searching a term, and i want to get the value from the searchbox by id.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "info"
});
var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36')
casper.start("http://www.google.com/ncr", function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
}).viewport(1366, 768);

//casper.then(function() {
//this.sendKeys('#gbqfq', 'Duke');
//this.click('#gbqfsa');
//});
casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="gbqfq"]'), function () {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = "samearga";
        this.echo(this.document.getElementById('gbqfq').value);
    });
    console.log("\nEXISTA SELECTORUL!!! -> document.getElementById('gbqfq').value\n");
});

casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="gbqfq"]'), function () {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    });
    console.log("\nSUBMITING!!!\n");
});

casper.wait(4000, function () {
    console.log("\nFAC POZA\n");
    casper.capture('caca.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I am retrieving so i can see that i can do it. Indentation is ruined by stackoverflow code feature. sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities to get the value of an input on the page.

1. You can either register to [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) event and log it on the page

   ```
   // at the beginning of the script
   casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
       this.echo("remote> " + msg);
   });

   // inside of the step
   casper.evaluate(function () {
       document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = "samearga";
       console.log(document.getElementById('gbqfq').value);
   });
   ```
2. or return the string from the page context

   ```
   // inside of the step
   var inputValue = casper.evaluate(function () {
       document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = "samearga";
       return document.getElementById('gbqfq').value;
   });
   casper.echo(inputValue);
   ```

You have to keep in mind what `this` means. Inside of the page context (inside of `casper.evaluate`) `this` refers to `window`, but `window` doesn't have an `echo` function. Page and casper contexts are distinct from one another (sandboxed) and you can't just use all variables. More in the [docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate).

Comment: I tried it too, the first solution works, thank you a million.