# waitforSelector function in casperjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

hello I am new to Casper and node

I am trying to run a code that scrpping data from a site

but WaitForselector function is not working correctly .

my code is

```
casper.waitForSelector('.searchAutoSuggstn', function() {

   this.echo('Search auto suggestion.');   // this line is printing my console
    var data = this.evaluate(function() {
        var suggestions = [];
        this.echo('Search auto suggestion  data.');  //But this line is not printing my console

        var element = $('.searchAutoSuggstn .suggestionsList_menu').find('.topProdhead_left').prevAll().filter(function() { 
            this.echo('omnitrack');
          return $(this).data("omnitrack") ;
        });
```

is any boddy can tell me whats the main problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract an input value by id with CasperJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150647/how-can-i-extract-an-input-value-by-id-with-casperjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call casper methods such as casper.echo() in casper.evaluate() since evaluate executes code in the context of the browser.

You could use console.log in the browser to output to the javascript console which you can then catch with the hook

```
casper.on("remote.messsage", function(msg){
// Do something
});
```